# How to use skype API in C# .net web development

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, skype4com, skype-uri.js

I try to make a skype call using **SKYPE4COMLib** library but its worked only for once

```
            Call call = skype.PlaceCall(username);
            do
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            } while (call.Status != TCallStatus.clsInProgress);
            call.StartVideoSend();
```

At the second try id didn't work.
And also I try to make a skype call using skype button

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_skypename_1">
 <script type="text/javascript">
     Skype.ui({
         "name": "call",
         "element": "SkypeButton_Call_skypename_1",
         "participants": ["skypename"]
     });
 </script>

</div>
```

It works well.But It opens original skype software and make calls. I need to add a widget into my asp.net MVC web page and then make skype calls within my web page and capture some details(call start time,end time,record call) and store them in my database.Is there any way to do that. I didn't got any valuable solution for this.

Thank You

Comment: Note that the C# version calls from the *server*, not the browser (although in your dev setup they are probably on the same PC and it **seems** to work)

Answer (score 2):

The Skype URIs do not work "inside" your web application. All they do is call the installed Skype software. Skype cannot do any callbacks to your website, and it is not designed to do so.

Which, in turn, doesn't make this a C# question, but rather a JavaScript issue:

The [Skype Web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962133%28v=office.16%29.aspx) will enable you to do more of what you want, but it is only in "Preview" state and for "Skype for Business".